# swift: chat app - audio player within cells

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

My app allows users to send audio just like in a typical messaging app.
The problem is that every time a new message comes in and therefor I'm refreshing my collectionView, the audio stops.

Right at the moment I have a AVPlayer within the message cell itself.

Is there any better way and how can I ensure, that the audio won't stop playing when the collectionView is refreshed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solultion was pretty simple. Since I was reloading the complete collectionView

```
DispatchQueue.main.async{
   self.collectionView.reloadData()
   (...)
}
```

This problem had to come up. I solved it by only inserting new cells or reloading specific cells instead of reloading the complete collectionView.

Comment: How are you handling play/pause? Playing audio and pause in between then again play from the same duration where I have paused

Comment: How is your specific case? Do you mean within the cells?

In my case I have an audioplayer within the `UICollectionViewCell`
 and I am only reloading specific cells instead of the complete `UICollectionView`. This allows the different audioplayers to handle that by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare you player like this

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaToolbox
import MediaPlayer

class MusicPlayer: NSObject {

    static let player = MusicPlayer()

    //this is global variable
    var player : AVPlayer?
    var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?

    func initPlayer(){
        do {
            UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
            print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

                print("AVAudioSession is Active")

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
}
    func playMusic(_ musicUrl: String?) {
        if let mm = musicUrl {
            var url: URL!
            url = URL(string: mm)
            playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
            player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            player?.volume = 1.0
            player?.rate = 1.0
            player?.play()

        }
    }

}
```

After you can initialize this in your AppDelegate like this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    MusicPlayer.player.initPlayer()


    return true
}
```

After that player usages like this

```
MusicPlayer.player.playMusic(YourFile)
```

Comment: Thank‘s for the answer! Unfortunately I needed another solution.